# Formula to find latitude and longitude of a point in an image with this information.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsvrf.png)

Please look at the image. I know the latitude and longitude of four corners of the image.

I also know the width & height of the image.

I also know the blue point's location using pixels in the image. (Example 300px top and 400px from left).

I want to know the Latitude and Longitude of the blue point in the above image.

Comment: The heading has a typo, "latitude and latitude"

Comment: Fixed. Do you have any idea how to do this? Or tell me what to type on google?

Comment: You don't show any attempts?  Try expressing your corner values completely in decimal degrees and then using ratios with top to bottom and left to right pixels.

Comment: I tried the simple ratio thing, but it is not simple ratio.

Comment: See the latitude lines. They are not straight, they are curved. this is probably the reason? https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Redmond_Shamshiri/publication/288530122/figure/fig5/AS:311818158395396@1451354650145/Latitude-and-Longitude-representation.png

Comment: What sort of map is this? Mercator projection?

Comment: No idea, I am using Google earth to take screenshot of image and find lat/long of four corners currently